# Case conditions giving not expected results

Tags: postgresql

In my query i have some case condition to look over hours in `lastoccurrence` column then as shown in specific cases it should print in `aging_range` column either `6 hrs, 12 hrs, 24 hrs, 48 hrs or else > 1 week`. Problem is even if as in picture `hours = 1` i receive `> 1 week`. What is wrong with my query?

**Query:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schemaA.test
AS SELECT tableA.lastoccurrence,
    date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) AS hours,
    date_part('days'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) AS days,
    age(timezone('GMT'::text, now()), tableA.lastoccurrence) AS age,
        CASE
            WHEN date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) >= 1::double precision AND date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) <= 6::double precision AND date_part('days'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) = 0::double precision THEN '6 hrs'::text
            WHEN date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) >= 7::double precision AND date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) <= 12::double precision AND date_part('days'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) = 0::double precision THEN '12 hrs'::text
            WHEN date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) >= 13::double precision AND date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) <= 24::double precision AND date_part('days'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) = 0::double precision THEN '24 hrs'::text
            WHEN date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) >= 25::double precision AND date_part('hours'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) <= 48::double precision AND date_part('days'::text, timezone('GMT'::text, now()) - tableA.lastoccurrence) = 0::double precision THEN '48 hrs'::text
            ELSE '> 1 week'::text
        END AS aging_range
         FROM tmp.tableA;
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Works for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6184f35ebe15174443e37c68bce26c21 Which type is lastoccurrence?

Comment: Btw: You are calling the same function again and again. That has a huge impact on your performance. Try to execute it only once. Furthermore calling now() several times could give you unprecise result because each call is on different time, so every now() call has different result.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ed946f16fe08232636f03722e0f812c2

Comment: @S-Man `now()` is `STABLE` and will always return the same result.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks!

Comment: @S-Man what you propose? Could you post some solution as an answer?

Comment: I posted a link to a working fiddle above. As stated: I have no problem with your code. Maybe you could adjust the fiddle to reproduce your problem. I just enhanced your query with lesser code replication

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the timestamps were less than an hour in the past when you ran the query, and your `CASE` statement doesn't contain a case for “hours = 0”, so the `ELSE` branch was taken.

The `CASE` expression is overly complicated. I suggest something like:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN age(lastoccurrence AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') > '1 week'
          THEN '> 1 week'
          WHEN age(lastoccurrence AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') > '2 days'
          THEN '1 week'
          WHEN age(lastoccurrence AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') > '1 day'
          THEN '2 days'
          WHEN age(lastoccurrence AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') > '12 hours'
          THEN '1 day'
          WHEN age(lastoccurrence AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') > '6 hours'
          THEN '12 hours'
          ELSE '6 hours'
       END
FROM tmp.tablea;
```

Comment: why UTC? I need to use GMT, can i simply replace to GMT and use your code instead of mine?

Comment: Yes, sure. Aren't they synonyms?